# php Youtube Get video id from live_stream

Tags: php, youtube

How YouTube Get video id from live_stream using php. I using this url

```
 https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCmyKnNRH0wH-r8I-ceP-dsg
```

I try this code but return nothing

```
function getvideourl($chid){
$videoId = null;

// Fetch the livestream page
if($data = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel='.$chid))
{
    // Find the video ID in there
    if(preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $link, $matches))
        $videoId = $matches[1];
    
    else
        $videoId ="";
}
else
    throw new Exception('Couldn\'t fetch data');

 $video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videoId;


return $video_url;
}
```

Comment: [`parse_url()`](https://3v4l.org/7iRuu) was so much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the variable `$link` instead of `$data`, try change it like this:

```
if(preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $data, $matches))
        $videoId = substr($matches[0], 0, -2);
```